# Test OData Batch request from Postman

Tags: odata, postman

I need to test an OData batch request with multiple requests. But unable to invoke the batch request from Postman since it needs to pass the request through the body of the batch request.

Sample URL I tested

[https://myhost/sampleservice/odata.svc/$batch](https://hmyhost/sampleservice/odata.svc/$batch)

But I need to pass the following other two GET Requests for the Entity "Customer" from the body.

- https://hmyhost/sampleservice/odata.svc/Customer/$count
- https://hmyhost/sampleservice/odata.svc/Customer?$skip=0&$top10

How to pass the above two requests through the body of the batch request from Postman